# How to add a text to an image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, editing, flutter-web

How to add a text to an image in flutter web
How do I add text on the go to an image on flutter web? Is there widget for image editing. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you want when user click on the image, the app redirect to web right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any api for Image editor in flutter app. I need adding texts in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312047/is-there-any-api-for-image-editor-in-flutter-app-i-need-adding-texts-in-image)

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [custom painting (other answer found by @F-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312047/is-there-any-api-for-image-editor-in-flutter-app-i-need-adding-texts-in-image) or [stack other widget on top of your image (here is excellent example, with text on top of images as you might want](https://youtu.be/6FhWA6xbUuQ).

Answer (score 2):

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
 }

class MyApp  extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("Add Text to an Image"),
     ),
     body:Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           Image.network("http://www.panama-offshore-services.com/wp- 
      content/uploads/2014/08/Tech-business-panama.jpg"),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
          ),
          Text("This is text",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                fontSize: 18.0
            ),)
           ],
        ),
       )
      ),
     );
    }

    }







  // use stack to add text on image
```

Comment: Would you be capable of saving this image with the text?