# Is there a way to print the same exact page on flutter web?

Tags: flutter, pdf, web

i'm trying to make a page with flutter widgets and i want the user to be able to print the same exact page.

**I have tried:**
syncfusion_flutter_pdf library
Which is work fine but i cant make complex designs.
PDF library
Unfortunately i couldn't figure it out because i'm using dart:html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output a Flutter scene exactly as they appear on the screen, you can use a `RepaintBoundary` widget, to save the widget into a PNG file.

You can insert `RepaintBoundary` at any level of the widget tree. So if you put it near the root of the widget tree, you will be able to capture the whole screen.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312516/1032613) for how to use `RepaintBoundary`.